# Get all records from more than one table with the same columns

Tags: sql

I have 3 tables in my database, those 3 tables have common columns. Column #1 is `Name`, column #2 is `printed` and column #3 is `location`.

What I'm trying to do is get all records from those 3 tables

```
where printed = "NO" and location = "Submitted"
```

Something like

```
select * 
from table1, table2, table3 
where printed = "NO" and Location = "Submitted"
```

Is this available?

Comment: It is possible with `union`

Comment: Cannot be MySQL and SQL-Server, they are different products

Comment: First figure out which RDBMS you're using (maybe JohnHC already figured this out for you). Then see http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Double quotes are for delimited identifiers (e.g. `"Column Name"`), use single quotes for string literals, e.g. `'some text'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all 3 tables have the same structure:

```
select t1.*
from table1 t1
where printed = 'NO' and Location = 'Submitted'
union 
select t2.*
from table2 t2
where printed = 'NO' and Location = 'Submitted'
union 
select t3.*
from table3 t3
where printed = 'NO' and Location = 'Submitted'
```

If structure is different (ie, different columns in each table):

```
select t1.somecolumn, t1.someothercolumn, t1.etc
from table1 t1
where printed = 'NO' and Location = 'Submitted'
union 
select t2.somecolumn, t2.someothercolumn, t2.etc
from table2 t2
where printed = 'NO' and Location = 'Submitted'
union 
select t3.somecolumn, t3.someothercolumn, t3.etc
from table3 t3
where printed = 'NO' and Location = 'Submitted'
```

A union MUST return columns of the same datatype, and returns them in the order selected, defined by the 1st select... If you have duplicates, `UNION` will remove them. If you want to keep your duplicates, use `UNION ALL` instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `union` to achieve the outcome. `Union` appends the resultsets of separate queries:

```
select name, printed, location from table1 where printed = "NO" and Location = "Submitted"
union
select name, printed, location from table2 where printed = "NO" and Location = "Submitted"
union
select name, printed, location from table3 where printed = "NO" and Location = "Submitted"
```

If you would like to know from which table a particular record came from, then add a constant field to each of the queries:

```
select name, printed, location, "table1" as table_name from table1 where printed = "NO" and Location = "Submitted"
...
```

Comment: Watch out for the quotes, I nearly missed it myself

Comment: @JohnHC Both MySQL and ms sql work with double quotes

Comment: Well, every day is a school day